# ASP.Net MVC and Database Connections

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, model-view-controller

I currently have an ASP.NET MVC application that has a static class to connect to the database. In some tests, I noticed that when I start using the application from several different sessions, it is getting extremely slow. If I only have one session, it works in an acceptable way, but from 3 sessions the usage starts to become unfeasible.

The static connection is starting in the Application_Start of Global.asax, I believe that this slowness is due to all of them competing for the same connection, right?

Given this, I decided to change the operation of the same, but I have two approaches that I think to follow, but I would like an opinion to know which would be the best:

1) Establish a session connection started in Global.asax, however I am afraid that due to certain actions that the application executes almost simultaneously, this approach is also slow at a given time.

2) Establish a connection for each query action to the database, instantiating the connection, opening the connection, executing the action and closing the connection. But again, due to the high number of actions that the application performs when loading some pages, I'm afraid to pop the connection pool by working this way.

Can you help me? Do you have a vision of another approach that can be used?

Currently, we are using ADO.Net and in some tests, we did with NHibernate even with just one user the gigantic slowness.

I thank the attention.
(Translated Post)

Comment: The question should be in english. You can try https://pt.stackoverflow.com/

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use Entity Framework.

http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/what-is-entityframework.aspx

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application

Assuming that you have the application(ASP.NET MVC) and database already created you need to opne Visual Studio, select the Models folder>Add>New Item an than you need to choose ADO.NET Entity Data Model. After that you will see the Entity Data  Model Wizard. From that window choose the first option, Ef Designer from Database. Click next, add the db connection parameters(db server, database name), click next, the the objects from db you want to use(tables, stored procedure) and click Finish

Hope it helps !